# How to detect only one face infront of a webcam

Tags: face-detection, opencv, python

I have done face detection program using Haar classifier but the problem is that it is detecting many faces while i need only one face detected even though many faces might come in front of the webcam/camera

Comment: Haar classifier based detectors return only the bounding box. So we have limited options for filtering out irrelevant faces. A simple criteria can be the face size where we can assume that we require only the face which is closest to the camera. Compute the area of all faces and keep the one with maximum area.

Comment: But what are your criteria? I mean face detection happens when a face is spotted/detected, so no verification is done. And if you want to detect one face, must it be detected randomly?